# eigenvectors of a unit lower triangular matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab

I know that for a lower triangular matrix, its eigenvalues are equal to its diagonal elements. And if we assume a unit lower triangular matrix, its eigenvalues are all equal to 1 (since it is a unit lower triangular matrix).

My question is what are the eigenvectors of a unit lower triangular matrix? there exists a specific property about its eigenvectors?

For example, if we consider a unit lower triangular matrix A = [1,0,0; 4,1,0; 12,24,1].

Using matlab, I am calculating its eigenvalues and eigenvectors using the command `eig`. For example `[e l] = eig(A)`. I am always getting a matrix e where all its elements are equal to 0 but the last line is equal to 1.

So does a unit lower triangular matrix can be expressed as the product of E*D*E'where E is the eigenvector matrix and D is the eigenvalues matrix and ' designates the transpose operator? But I am pretty sure that the elements of its eigenvector matrix should not be equal to 0..
Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: See example in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1239343/how-to-find-a-eigenvector-with-a-repeated-eigenvalue?rq=1

Comment: Does $E'$ mean transpose or inverse?  Either way, think of about what $D$ looks like exactly and you'll see that $EDE'$ is equivalent to something simpler...

Comment: for the unit lower triangular matrix case, the D here is simply the identity matrix.

Comment: @Christina So what you're asking is whether a unit lower triangular matrix can be written as $EE'$.  Since $EE'$ is always symmetric, this is impossible unless the lower triangular matrix is also upper triangular: that's a lot of zeros :).

Comment: exactly, a unit lower triangular matrix is then written as EE', but what are the properties about the values of E?

Comment: What's happening here is that unit triangular matrices (except for the identity) never have a full set of eigenvectors.  In the generic case (all sub-diagonal entries are non-zero), there is only the one independent eigenvector, and that's what Matlab is indicating.  There can be more eigenvectors if the matrix has more zeroes.

Comment: Ok but if you change the values of the matrix A that I gave in my question, you will always get the same eigenvector matrix where all its elements are equal to zero except the last line which contains the ones. So this is not logic! So I think a unit lower triangular matrix cannot be written in the form EE'. What is your opinion? :)

Comment: @Christina: What Erick says is that the _only_ triangular matrices that can be written as $EE^T$ are the diagonal matrices (because those are the only matrices that are both triangular and symmetric). If your matrix is not _already_ diagonal, then it cannot be written as $EE^T$.

Comment: Ah ok :) thank you for your help Henning:) and thank you so much Erik :)

Comment: But if we know now that all the eigenvalues are equal to 1, we cannot express E as a specific equation? Thank you so much for your time:)